# refart with Fancyhdr - header width

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, width

When I create the header with `fancyhdr` the seperation line between the header and the body is only same wide as text bodys. When a new part starts, this looks quite strange as the part seperation lines are at full page width.

How can I get the header seperation line to the same widht as the part.
I searched and found several descriptions for the `fancyhdr` package, but none covered my problem so far.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{refart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
%\pagestyle{headings}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Test}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}

    \part{Part 1}
        \section{Bla Bla}
        \lipsum
    \newpage
    \part{Part 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line after `\pagestyle{fancy}`:

```
\fancyhfoffset[L]{\leftmarginwidth}
```